# Add border if its greater the array css inside js

Tags: javascript, css

can someone please help me, I have this code:

```
<?php $users= count($other_users); // result 3
$groups= count($test_invited_groups); // result 4
 ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var other_users= <?php echo json_encode($users ); ?>;
    var groups= <?php echo json_encode($groups ); ?>;
    if (groups > other_users) {
            document.getElementById('list_users').style.border-left = '1px solid red';
     }else{
            document.getElementById('list_users').style.border-left = 'none';  
     }

</script>
```

Why the border is not showing what I am doing wrong..? Anyone..?

Comment: borderLeft instead ... you sould get JS error by the way

Comment: What exactly are the values/us meant by these: `groups > other_users`? Are those numbers? If they are arrays you should properly use something related to that. Since the PHP part here is irrelevant post the actual values from the rendered page.  Isolating questions to a minimal reproducible example that we can test/use is the best way to get great answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript is wrong.
Try to write style properties with camelCase.

```
document.getElementById('list_users').style.borderLeft = "1px solid red"
```

This is because Javascript sees the `-` as an operator, so every two-word (or more) CSS property is written in camelCase.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `border-left` to `borderLeft`

In Javascript **properties** should be written in **camelCase**.  The minus sign `-` is treated as an operator.

```
<?php
$users = count($other_users); // result 3
$groups = count($test_invited_groups); // result 4
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var other_users = <?php echo json_encode($users); ?>;
    var groups = <?php echo json_encode($groups); ?>;
    if (groups > other_users) {
        document.getElementById('list_users').style.borderLeft = '1px solid red';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('list_users').style.borderLeft = 'none';
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You should also explain your changes and not just post the whole code.